# Вставить массив значений

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Возможно ли в OLEDB при работе с excel в update указать не одно значение, а массив? При больших объемах данных делать update для каждой строки отдельно выходит достаточно затратно по времени

Comment: Приведите для наглядности пример команд (приведите код), которые вы пытаетесь сделать несколько операций.

Comment: @AK, обычный запрос. Например: `UPDATE [<лист>$C4:C4] SET F1 = '<значение>'` Но таких запросов (сейчас) >67000. Поэтому работает это крайне медленно

Comment: Похоже, что [такой функциональности](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13359748/5752652) до сих пор нет, максимум что можно посоветовать - использовать подготовленные выражения: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7213611/5752652

Comment: @AK, спасибо. Но в моем случае номер ячейки меняется при каждом запросе (обновляю столбец полностью). А параметром этот номер сделать не получится...